# Proftpd completely hide directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, hide, ftp-server

Within my ftp tree there is a directory that I don't want to be accessible via anonymous.

I am able to hide the directory in question and all the files within the directory.

What I have not been able to do is prevent somebody from navigating to the directory.

So if somebody navigates to ftp.site.com they wont see an 'incoming' directory.  However, if they navigate to ftp.site.com/incoming the page loads.

The files are hidden but this kind of nullifies the point of hiding the 'incoming' directory in the first place.

Any ideas would be much appreciated and if I've left anything out please me know.

Here are my configurations.

```
drwxr-xr-x  29 john     ftpgroup 4096 2012-04-17 22:22 incoming

<Anonymous /home/ftp/ftp.site.com>
    User  ftp
    Group ftp
    UserAlias    anonymous ftp

    <Directory incoming/>
        HideGroup ftpgroup

        <Limit READ DIRS>
            IgnoreHidden on
        </Limit>
    </Directory>
</Anonymous>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the following lines, deny any access to that directory. Add the following lines to your configuration.

**`<Directory incoming`/*>

     AllowOverwrite no

    `<Limit READ`>

       DenyAll

    `</Limit`>

  `</Directory`>**

Thank you
Chakri